# How to use several custom filters with QFileDialog?

Tags: python, pyqt5

I'd like to use a `QFileDialog` in PyQt5 to match a custom pattern in filenames. The `getOpenFileName` method uses wildcards, which aren't powerful enough for my purposes. The most common solution is to inherit `QtCore.QSortFilterProxyModel`, override the `filterAcceptsRow` method and pass that class as a proxy to the QFileDialog. The problem is that you can only do that *once*. How one can cumulate several filters like this and make them appear as different selectable filters in the combobox of the QFileDialog ? The only solution I can think of would be to write my own "open file" widget.

**Edit 0 :** In the following minimal example, we display a window with a button, that button opening a QFileDialog window, in which we display the files having no dot in their name, and the directories. I'd like to do the following :

- In the combobox displaying the type of the files (which correspond to a filter), give the correct name, instead of the default one. I know this is the result of replacing the behaviour with the proxy, and I thought using `setFilterName` would do the trick, but it changes the behaviour.
- I'd like to have several of those filters, displayed in the combobox, with the correct names and behaviour, and as I understand things (maybe the wrong way), `QtCore.QSortFilterProxyModel` only allows for one filter type (which can filter many things, but will still be one item in the combobox). What if I want to add the behaviour of the "All files (*)" filter for example ?

```py
import sys
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication, QMainWindow, QPushButton, QFileDialog

class ProxyModel(QtCore.QSortFilterProxyModel):
    def filterAcceptsRow(self, source_row, source_parent):
        model = self.sourceModel()
        index = model.index(source_row, 0, source_parent)
        return (model.isDir(index) or '.' not in model.fileName(index))

    def sort(self, column, order):
        self.sourceModel().sort(column, order)


class MyWindow(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.initUI()

    def initUI(self):
        self.setGeometry(100, 100, 300, 200)
        self.setWindowTitle('File Dialog Example')
        self.button = QPushButton('Open File Dialog')
        self.button.clicked.connect(self.showFileDialog)
        self.setCentralWidget(self.button)


    def showFileDialog(self):
        dialog = QFileDialog()
        dialog.setOption(QFileDialog.DontUseNativeDialog)
        dialog.setProxyModel(ProxyModel())
        if dialog.exec_():
            fileName=dialog.selectedFiles()[0]
        else:
            return
        if fileName:
            print("Selected file: ", fileName)



if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    window = MyWindow()
    window.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

**Edit 1 :** As my request seems still unclear, I develop here a bit more. Maybe the unclearness is coming from the fact that the behaviour I want is obvious for most programmers but not for me, because I'm discovering Qt, and I may be overcomplicating things.

I display below the interface obtained by running the code above, after clicking the button. I added the big red box at the bottom, which enclose the combobox at the bottom. A combobox is a sort of drop-down list where the user can either type a value directly or select a value from the list (the latest being the case here). In this case, the call to `setProxyModel` with our custom filter (which selects directories and files with not dot in their names) in the code replaced the *behaviour* of the default combobox (which displays all files) but not the name of the filter. So we have a combobox that says "All files (*)" and displays the files filtered by our custom filter. I'd like to change that in order for the box to display a name that would actually describe what the filter does, "Files with no dots !(*.*)" for instance.

[image: What you obtain running the code]

For the second (actually main) question, "How one can cumulate several  filters ?", I will give a basic example and detail what I want. A common use of `QFileDialog` is to call `getOpenFileName`, a static method, with several filters. For instance, using

```py
QFileDialog.getOpenFileName(self, 'Open file', ".", "Images (*.png *.xpm *.jpg);;Text files (*.txt);;XML files (*.xml)", option = QFileDialog.DontUseNativeDialog)
```

will open the same window with different items (filters) in the combobox, filtering the displayed files according to their extension. Selecting `"Images (*.png *.xpm *.jpg)"` in the combobox will only display files matching the wildcard patterns `(*.png *.xpm *.jpg)`, same for text and xml files (respectively to their patterns).
What I'd like is to be able to cumulate the same way several custom filters, using (or not, because it's too limiting) wildcards. Fox example, how do I add the "All files" filter in the combobox list alongside my custom filter ?

Comment: You can implement `filterAcceptsRow()` in any way you want, including using multiple patterns. Either use multiple if/elif checks, or the switch/case syntax. If you need more help on this, please provide a valid [mre] with some example patterns you want to match.

Comment: I'm not sure I completely understand your request. Please explain what you mean by: 1. "In the combobox [...] give the correct name, instead of the default one"; 2. "How one can cumulate several filters". Also, as already requested, provide some example patterns you want to match (possibly with step-by-step behaviors) so we can better understand what you actually want to do. Remember that we know nothing about your program or concept, and while your explanation may seem obvious to you, it may not be clear to us (see [rubber duck debugging](//en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rubber_duck_debugging)).